# Mock internal method with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermock

I have 2 methods, first method in jpa class to find id and another method to create a record (which checks whether the id already exists and creates a record if the record with id doesn't exists).

```
public class EmployeeRegistry{
public Employee findEmployeeById(String empid){
     List<Employee> results = new ArrayList<Employee>();
     final Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("employeeRegistryImpl.findByEmployeeId");
     query.setParameter("empid", empid);

     results = (List<Employee>) query.getResultList();

     if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(results)) {            
        return null;
     }
     return results.get(0);
}

public Employee createEmployee(final Employee employee) throws PersistenceException{
    if ((findEmployeeById(employee.getId()!=null)) {
        throw new EntityExistsException();
    }
    return entitytManager.merge(employee);
}
}
```

I wrote test cases with JUnit and Mockito frameworks for first method, findEmployeeById. e.g.,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeRegistryImplTest{

private String empid = "empid";

@Mock
private static EntityManager entityManager;
@Mock
private static Query query;

@InjectMocks
private static EmployeeRegistry employeeRegistryImpl;

@Test
public void findEmployeeByIdReturnsNull() {

  final List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

  // given
given(entityManager.createNamedQuery("employeeRegistryImpl.findByEmployeeId")).willReturn(query);
given(query.setParameter("empid", empid)).willReturn(query);
given(query.getResultList()).willReturn(employees);

// when
Employee employeeResult = null;
employeeResult = employeeRegistryImpl.findEmployeeById(empid);

// then
assertNull(employeeResult);
verify(entityManager, Mockito.times(1)).createNamedQuery
("employeeRegistryImpl.findEmployeeById");
}
```

I tried to write the test case for createEmployee

```
@Test
public void createEmployeeReturnsNotNull() {    
    final Employee employee= new Employee();

    // when
    Employee employee= null;
    employeeResult = employeeRegistryImpl.createEmployee(employee);

    assertNotNull(employeeResult);
}
```

Since the createEmployee method calls internally findEmployeeById and will get NullPointerException, how can i mock the findEmployeeById (and empid as an input to the same method) for createEmployee method in my test class, EmployeeRegistryTest.

-- Added spying after checking spy from Mockito documentation and gets NullPointerException for empid.

```
@Test
public void createEmployeeReturnsNotNull() {
 final Employee employee = new Employee();
 employee.setEmpId(empid);
 final Employee employee2 = new Employee();
 employee2.setEmpId(empid);
 EmployeeRegistryImpl spy = Mockito.spy(employeeRegistryImpl);

    // when
    Employee employeeResult = null;
    try {
        doReturn(employee2).when(spy).findEmployeeById(empid);
        employeeResult = employeeRegistryImpl
                .createUser(employee);

                    // then
        verify(spy).findEmployeeById(empid);

        assertNotNull(employeeResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

-- Exception after spying
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at EmployeeRegistryImpl.findEmployeeById(EmployeeRegistryImpl.java:)
  at EmployeeRegistryImpl.createEmployee(EmployeeRegistryImpl.java:)
  at EmployeeRegistryImplTest.createEmployeeReturnsNotNull(EmployeeRegistryImplTest.java:)
```

Comment: Read chapters 13 and 16 of http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html. While you're at it, read all the other ones.

Comment: Thanks! that gave me an idea of spying the object. So i added the spying in my edited post and get NullPointerException.

Comment: It's not clear where you're getting the exception - *always* post the errors you're trying to fix. It might have something to do with the fact that you're returning `null` in your mocked method, though.

Comment: Yes, query in findEmployeeById method is expecting empid and its null, do i need to spy the empid as well. I don't think i can spy the String object right.

Comment: It's still not clear where you're getting the error. *Post the exception*, and identify where in the code it happens.

Comment: I added the exception to my edited post. I can't post the line numbers from the exception trace as the code is slightly more than the posted code here.

Comment: That could shouldn't be running at all, since you want to mock that method. So you're doing something wrong that's causing the non-mocked method to be called. Try calling `createUser` on the spied object, not on `employeeRegistryImpl`.

Comment: Seems like calling createUser on the spied object covered the test case for throwing EntityExistsException. I don't understand the reason for calling createUser on spied object but let me understand and will check for test case creating the user now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Answer posted below

I learnt that i don't actually need to spy, i can just mock the internal method as well and that works :)

e.g.,

```
@Test
public void createEmployeeThrowsExceptionWhenEmployeeExists() {
 final Employee employee= new Employee();       
 employee.setEmpId(empId);

final List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employeeList.add(new employee());

// given
given(entityManager.createNamedQuery("employeeRegistryImpl.findByEmployeeId")).willReturn(query);
given(query.setParameter("empId", empId)).willReturn(query);
given(query.getResultList()).willReturn(employeeList);

// when
try {
    employeeRegistryImpl.createUser(employeeList);      
} catch (Exception e) {
// then
    e.getErrorCode());
}

// then
verify(entityManager, Mockito.times(1)).
createNamedQuery("employeeRegistryImpl.findByEmployeeId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new internal class in testcase extends EmployeeRegistry, and override method "findEmployeeById" and call "createEmployee" of new class.